# Finding probability of occurrence in non-standard distributions

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

I'm writing a program that uses standard deviation as a threshold to detect outliers, however I understand that this assumes a normal distribution, however the data I'm using can assume any distribution.  My plan is to first determine the type of distribution, then find the probability of certain values appearing based on the size of the data set and setting the outlier threshold based on number of standard deviations expected.  For example, if n = 100, I wouldn't expect to see anything 4 standard deviations, but if n=1,000,000 then this it would be expected.

The question is this:  Assuming I know the underlying distribution, how can I determine the number of expected observations at a given standard deviation (ie. given a gamma distribution and 500k values how many observations do I expect at 5 stdev, 10 stdev, etc.).

And I suppose, more fundamentally, is standard deviation even the right measure to use here or is there a different measure I should consider?

Thank you

Comment: For the first question, look at cumulative distribution functions. Fot the second question, yes there are plenty of methods for identifying outliers — but why do you want to identify outliers, what will you do with them and what will you do with the rest of the data?

Comment: The purpose of the detection is to identify data that may have been incorrectly entered, so the other data would be used for modeling or reporting

Comment: For detecting human errors in entering data with an unknown distribution, I wouldn’t use standard deviation: I would probably set a range of reasonable values (eg 1 to 1000) and reject entries outside that range, or entries with too many digits after the decimal point, or entries that arrived too close in time to other entries. That would allow for cleaner modeling than an sd-based approach, and might also  be more reliable.